# How fix no such NoSuchMethodError flutter tabView?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I try listView then make snackBar to output if listView tapped.
This is worked fine.

But when i put that listView in tabView, then the snackBar not appear and give NoSuchMethodError.

I put listView in third tab.

```
       TabBarView(
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.directions_car),
          _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.call, 'CALL'),
          new ListView(
              children: new List.generate(10, (int index){
                return new ListTile(title: new Text("item#$index"),
                  onTap:(){
                    setState((){
                      _id = index; //if you want to assign the index somewhere to check
                    });
                    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text("You clicked item number $_id")));
                  },
                );
              })
          ),
          Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
          Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Can you share console log with us?

Comment: I already know my mistake, its because context.
I change _scaffoldKey.currentState to Scaffold.of(context)
Thank you for try help me

Answer (score 0):

context error

using Builder()

for example

```
            return Builder(builder: (context){
                return new ListTile(title: new Text("item#$index"),
                  onTap:(){
                    setState((){
                    });
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                      content: new Text("Hello! I am SnackBar :) "),
                      duration: new Duration(seconds: 3),
                    ));
                  },
                );
              })
```